# How to determine if the sum of two binary numbers using 8-bit register will overflow for unsigned and signed integers?

Tags: computer-science

You are given a sum of binary numbers: 0b01001010 + 0b01001010. Consider using 8-bit register

Will the computation of the unsigned integers result in overflow?
Will the computation of signed two's complement numbers results in overflow?

When i added the two binary numbers the result was  0b10010100 which is till in the range of 8 bit register so it shouldnt result in an overflow but for signed i dont know if it should or shouldnt overflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The standard rule for overflow for addition of two signed numbers it that an overflow has occurred if (1) the two numbers have the same sign, (2) their sum has the other sign.

You've added two positive numbers (the sign bit is 0) and the result is a negative number (the sign bit is 1).